# How do I pivot a matrix rotation on a point other than 0,0 when using PathMeasure.getMatrix()

Tags: android, matrix, path, rotation

I'm moving a bitmap along a path on a Canvas. The path has various curves and the bitmap follows along. pm.getMatrix does a really lovely job of handling the position and rotation adjustments along the path when its passed the PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG and TANGENT_MATRIX_FLAG, however, it rotates the bitmap pivoted on the 0,0 coordinate.  I need it to pivot on the center of the bitmap.

I cracked open the matrix in the debugger, and it appears that there is indeed *no spoon.  There is however 3 arrays of floats, each containing 3 floats.  I'm guessing that if I can get those values, I can probably figure out which of them describes the rotation of the object, and there's probably some way to alter the pivot point?  I see no other way to do it... Would love some guidance on at least what those three float arrays actually describe.

```
PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(playerPath, false);
float fSegmentLen = pm.getLength() / numSteps;
Matrix mxTransform = new Matrix();

pm.getMatrix(fSegmentLen * iCurStep, mxTransform,
                    PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG + PathMeasure.TANGENT_MATRIX_FLAG );
canvas.drawBitmap(playerCar, mxTransform, null);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
private void setDrawingMatrix(float distance) {
    pm.getMatrix(distance, mxTransform, PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG | PathMeasure.TANGENT_MATRIX_FLAG);
    mxTransform.preTranslate(-playerCar.getWidth() / 2.0f, -playerCar.getHeight() / 2.0f);
}
```

and then in onDraw method:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(playerCar, mxTransform, null);
```

happy driving...

Comment: that totally works... thanks... if you have a moment to explain what it's actually doing, I'd really appreciate it... why does moving the car over -1/2width and -1/2height make it rotate on its center?

Comment: dont worry if you dont get it, (the docs dont help much...) it is still a kind of black magic to me, but reading this http://jaypthakkar.blogspot.com/2013/04/the-role-of-transformation-matrices-in.html?m=1 may help...

Comment: btw, see the difference if you use postTranslate vs preTranslate

Comment: funny... I'm actually familiar with the stuff at that link.  This particular translation is more mysterious because I have no visibility into what pm.getMatrix() actually does.  However, I suspect that the reason it works as it does is that preTranslate affects the values that were there to begin with, so, in essence, it shifts the car over by 1/2 its with on both axis and then the rotation still *thinks it's rotating the 0,0 coordinate, it's just that now the center of the car is at that coordinate. (at least that's my guess).

Comment: i couldnt explain better :) its a pity that docs are so poor in that matter the best thing is just to call pre/pist Teanslate/Scale/Rotate and see how this affect car's path in comparison to the road

Comment: speaking of matrices, see below post how cute things you can do with them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729169/how-to-maintain-multi-layers-of-imageviews-and-keep-their-aspect-ratio-based-on/