# convert two images in bitmap and one image mask them

Tags: android, merge, mask

i have two images one is background image and another is small image whick i want to mask on background image.i want like this![image]

Comment: That's iPhone to Android homework.

Comment: yes i want to convert iPhone app into android

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729169/how-to-maintain-multi-layers-of-imageviews-and-keep-their-aspect-ratio-based-on

Comment: give me some suggestion about this

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).

**EDIT:**

As [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) points out, [this class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16800944/2066079) might be better. Credit goes to him. Please thank that answer, not this one.