# To draw transparent line over image in imageview

Tags: android

I have made a paint app in which  i have used ImageView in layout  to show image that can be  taken from camera or gallery.I want to draw transparent line over image so that image can be seen after drawing.please help me.

Thanks for support

I have used the code to make draw line transparent is :

```
myPaint.setAlpha(50);
```

My code is:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
     Toast.makeText(PaintScreen.this, "onDraw is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     // myPaint.setAlpha(100); 
     canvas.drawBitmap(PaintScreen.this.localBitmap, 0,0,null); 
     //  canvas.drawPath(myPath, paintBlur); 
     canvas.drawPath(myPath, myPaint); Log.i("OnDRAWING", "REACH ON DRAW"); }


public class CustomView extends ImageView { 
      private float mX, mY; 

      public CustomView(Context context) { 
          super(context);        
          localBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
          myCanvas = new Canvas(localBitmap); 
          myPaint = new Paint(); setPaintForDraw(paintcolor, false, 30);                 
          setFocusable(true); 
          setFocusableInTouchMode(true); myPath = new Path(); 
      } 
}






private void setPaintForDraw(int color, boolean eraseMode, int brushSize) { 
          //myPaint.setAlpha(100); 
          myPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
          myPaint.setDither(true); 
          myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
          myPaint.setColor(color); 
          myPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);        
          myPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND); 
          myPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);  
          myPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
          if (eraseMode) { 
              myPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
          } 
          else { myPaint.setXfermode(null); }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

see this thread [How to maintain multi layers of ImageViews and keep their aspect ratio based on the largest one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729169/how-to-maintain-multi-layers-of-imageviews-and-keep-their-aspect-ratio-based-on), here you can use multiple Draeable layers that are drawn over the image

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check that your Bitmap is mutable. If it is not, make a copy of it. And here is how you can draw a line on your image:

```
Bitmap copyBmp = yourBMP.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true); //Copy if yourBMP is not mutable
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(copyBmp);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAlpha(50); //Put a value between 0 and 255
paint.setColor(Color.GRAY); //Put your line color
paint.setStrokeWidth(5); //Choose the width of your line
canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint); //Set the coordinates of the line
```

Now, if you display copyBmp, you should see a line drawn over it.

Comment: its work but problem is that when we remove finger and touch again then transparent color become dark

Comment: Is myPaint declared as a member of the class in which onDraw is implemented?