# Overlay png file over a picture Android

Tags: android, android-camera, image-capture, image-editing

I'm thinking to develop an app that should take a pic overlay over this pic a png image. For iOS I found some interesting on this link: [overlay image over another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020077/iphone-how-does-one-overlay-one-image-onto-another-to-create-a-new-image-to-sav).
Now I would do the same for an Android application, there's a way to do this stuff?
I need to develop quite the same app for iOS and for Android.
You suggest to use this way or you think it's better to implement something for augmented reality?

Comment: Here is a Question i asked similar to what u are expecting. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17671558/1567588. and I have got an answer for it. check if this helps.

Comment: My suggestion is to simply decrease the alpha layer of the top image if that is enough to satisfy your needs. I'll post the code later today.

Comment: Multiple surfacviews in the Z direction. You can set the transparency to zero on some of them. Use one for the Camera and others for a canvas to draw images to. Is this what you need?