# Zooming / panning more than one ImageView

Tags: android, zooming, android-imageview

I am using TouchImageView to zoom and pan images. I have 3 images. One is the background image which will be zoomed and panned by the user and I want the other 2 to zoom and pan accordingly. What modifications are necessary in the TouchImageView class to associate the 2 to the one that is being zoomed.

I've tried using the ZoomablePinView since it was a similar concept. I tried modifying it but was not successful.

Even if they're not suggestions regarding the TouchImageView, please do help out.
Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this answer?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know anything about TouchImageView, but when you refer to my answer in this post: [How to maintain multi layers of ImageViews and keep their aspect ratio based on the largest one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729169/how-to-maintain-multi-layers-of-imageviews-and-keep-their-aspect-ratio-based-on) maybe you could extend TouchImageView instead std ImageView