# Android: How do I align textview on a image background that dos not strech in xml

Tags: android, xml, image, layout

Ok here is the problem...
I have a image background that need some text and additional graphics on it. The background image needs to be in the center of the screen and may not stretch. Here is what i need to do:

[image]

The problem is that i need to align the text to the background image.
I've tried to wrap it all into a relative layout - something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bg_image"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/member_card"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/bg_image"
        android:text="@string/membercard_info"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />

<TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/bg_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This will not work since android adds additional padding to the image to avoid it from stretching.
Here is what happens in two different cases:
[image][image]

So how do I align the text to the background image?

I've solved this problem in the past in code by baking it all into one image,- but would like to do this in xml.

Comment: make your relativelayout wrap_content

Comment: I've tried that, but it dos not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove padding, you can use manually set it. However, if you want overlapping elements, you generally want to use FrameLayout. Look here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout/

Set a gravity inside the frame layout to align it.

Answer (score 0):

There a padding around the image because you set the imageView size to fill its parent ( using `match_parent` )

You should try to set it to wrap its content  :

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        .../>
```

**EDIT :** If your picture is bigger that the screen size, you need to have it scaled  keeping the aspect ratio.

To do this, use `match_parent` in vertical with a [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) to `FIT_CENTER` 
and keep the `wrap_content` setting for the width ( since we want the image view left/right bounds stuck to the image content )

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        .../>
```

Is this better ?

Comment: That only seems to make a difference when the image is smaller then the screen - so this won't solve it for me.... but it helps.

Comment: Edit :  I've added a setting to set the image fit its parent vertical size.

Comment: I'm afraid not.
I've added some pictures to explain what happens.

Comment: My solution should solve the second case (your second picture).  Does it ? ( so I can be sure I did understand what the problem is)

Answer (score 0):

if you want an ImageView with additional layers drawn on top of that, see this thread: [How to maintain multi layers of ImageViews and keep their aspect ratio based on the largest one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729169/how-to-maintain-multi-layers-of-imageviews-and-keep-their-aspect-ratio-based-on)