# Creating an 'Image Ribbon' overlaying a standard ImageView

Tags: android, android-canvas

I need to create a dynamic Ribbon View to overlay multiple images for promotional purposes.
Example (Sorry about the image, my Paintbrush skills are negligible):

[Example ImageView with Ribbon overlay](http://s17.postimg.org/d5c44a3uz/image_ribbon.jpg)

Where the grey box is my image and the orange strip with text is the ribbon.

After some research, my gut feel is to Extend a TextView, set the background as the ribbon colour, set the text, rotate using canvas, resize using recursion and somehow clipping the textview so the ribbon background colour goes all the way to the edges of the image below.

If all else fails, I will use 9-patch images, but am concerned in regards to the text resizing.

Any pointers/code snippets would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: see my answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729169/how-to-maintain-multi-layers-of-imageviews-and-keep-their-aspect-ratio-based-on, you can then modify it to meet your needs

Comment: @pskink Thank You, this is a great start! I still need to figure out how to size and clip the 'ribbon' view