# Android: How to place a transparent image over another image with its exact width and height

Tags: android

I have 2 images main_bg and a transparent image ship. Ship is cropped from main_bg and I want to place cropped image ship on main_bg on the exact position where ship appears on main_bg. When I use

`android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"`

ship appear as an elongated one. When I use "wrap_content" instead of "match_parent", 
it appear as a small image. How can I set ship on main_bg with its exact width and height.

This is my xml code.

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/main_bg" 
android:gravity="left" 
android:orientation="horizontal">
     <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/ship" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/ship" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I place it properly?

Comment: You can set the `src` and the `background` attributes to the layout (that's the foreground and the background of the layout).

Answer (score 0):

You should try using FrameLayouts to superimpose one image over the other. Like:

```
FrameLayout
    Image
FrameLayout
    Image
```

And set the dimensions of the FrameLayouts as you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `FrameLayout` and do something like this :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ship" >

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use LayeredImageView from this post [How to maintain multi layers of ImageViews and keep their aspect ratio based on the largest one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729169/how-to-maintain-multi-layers-of-imageviews-and-keep-their-aspect-ratio-based-on), see the example with a flag how to place layers