# I need to understand why setImageMatrix does not work

Tags: android, graphics

I am trying to create an android application (min SDK 14, target SDK 18) that works with images (move, scale, rotate).
I have done the move part.
But I can't make scale and rotate to work using Matrix.

According to what I have read, here is the code I am using for constructing an image view and do scale and rotate with Matrix.

```
public MyImage(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MyImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}

public void rotate(float angle) {
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.postRotate(angle);

    setImageMatrix(m);

    invalidate();
}

public void scale(float scaleFactor) {
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

    setImageMatrix(m);

    invalidate();
}
```

I have tried to use the set* functions of Matrix but that didn't work.
I have tried to set the scale type every time in rotate and scale functions instead of in init, but that didn't work.
I have tried to getImageMatrix instead of creating a new Matrix every time (i.e. creating an identity Matrix), but that didn't work.

I know that rotate and scale functions are getting called through debugger.

Obviously I am missing something.
I'm trying to understand what I am missing.

Should the above code work?
Have I misunderstood how Matrix works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see my anseer for that question [How to maintain multi layers of ImageViews and keep their aspect ratio based on the largest one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729169/how-to-maintain-multi-layers-of-imageviews-and-keep-their-aspect-ratio-based-on), that code uses layers that can ne transformed by any Matrix you want

Comment: thanks for the code. I see you are not using setImageMatrix and you do Matrix calculations in onDraw. It's different from my approach. I will give it a try.

Comment: Ok. A quick test I did was to create the matrix I want in rotate and scale and use it inside the draw function. It has started working! Thanks for the help!

Comment: of course you can use setImageMatrix as well, the point is to use new Matrix() and then call together preScale and/or preTranslate and/or preRotate on the same matrix